# Calculating points on Circle

Tags: math, geometry

I need to calculate the x and y points of the points A, B, C and D.
For that i need a formula. alpha and r are given.

And i need the 0 point on the top left corner. It cant get placed in the middle of the circle. Because i want to place elements on those points.

I would be realy thankfull for a formular that i can use ;D.

[image]

Comment: Do you know about sin and cos?

Comment: yeah, but math class is very far back. I tried to make a formular. But i cant remeber how you calculate those sites with cos and sin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax = 0
ay = r

bx = r - r * cos(alpha)
by = r + r * sin(alpha)

cx = r - r * cos(2*alpha)
```

and so on (3*alpha for D)